# Export Import Command Hazards in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use a machine learning library from [Github](https://github.com/mljs/ml). Using [decision trees](https://github.com/mljs/decision-tree-cart) example code, I got the error message "Unexpected token declaration" on the following row

```
import { DecisionTreeRegression as DTRegression } from 'ml-cart';
```

Given that import command is not fully supported by nodejs, I changed the above line to

```
var DTRegression = require ('ml-cart');
```

Now nodejs is flagging error on the subsequent statement `var reg = new DTRegression();` with message "DTRegression is not a constructor".
Looking through index.js file at ./node_modules/src/index.js, I can see the following code:

```
export { DecisionTreeClassifier } from './DecisionTreeClassifier';
export { DecisionTreeRegression } from './DecisionTreeRegression';
```

Then I tried directly referencing the ./node_modules/src/DecisionTreeRegression.js file using require command. That gave errors on 'export class' command inside DecisionTreeRegression.js.

Then I tried using the following command to make the import work.

```
node --experimental-modules myapp.mjs
```

I got the error "SyntaxError: The requested module 'ml-cart' does not provide an export named 'DecisionTreeRegression'".

Nodejs version is 10.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Best Regards,

Adeel

Answer (score 0):

Try the `mjs` extension here

`DecisionTreeRegression.mjs` when importing with

`node --experimental-modules myapp.mjs`

Comment: Hi @SushobhNadiger . Thanks for your suggestion. I have copied the index.js and DecisionTreeRegression.js to corresponding mjs extension. Still the error remains "import { DecisionTreeRegression as DTRegression } from 'ml-cart';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'ml-cart' does not provide an export named 'DecisionTreeRegression'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:89:21"